# SQL - Add Column Indicating if it's the first time an entry is seen

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table (call it FruitOrders) with many columns, one of which is fruit:

| Fruit | Order Time |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2022-09-09 22:21:03 |
| Banana | 2022-09-10 22:21:03 |
| Pineapple | 2022-09-11 22:21:03 |
| Orange | 2022-09-12 22:21:03 |
| Apple | 2022-09-13 22:21:03 |
| Orange | 2022-09-14 22:21:03 |
| Blueberry | 2022-09-15 22:21:03 |

I want to add a new column as a view where it will be "1" if it is the first row where the fruit is seen. An example is below:

| Fruit | First Time Seeing Fruit? |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |
| Banana | 1 |
| Pineapple | 1 |
| Orange | 1 |
| Apple | 0 |
| Orange | 0 |
| Blueberry | 1 |

Any thoughts on how to do this? I was guessing something involving partition/row_number but I'm new to using these. Also, this is a large table so if there are fast ways to do this let me know!

Comment: With just the column `Fruit` what you want isn't possible; you need a column to order your data by. What are the other columns in your data?

Comment: Or more simply, how do _you_ know which row is the "first" Apple?

Comment: I have a order time column as well in the FruitData table

Comment: [Edit] your question to demonstrate what your data *actually* looks like, @ZakFischer . Though you should be able to solve your problem rather simply with `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CASE` expression.

Comment: Ok I edited to add the extra column. In reality there are about 20 additional data columns so I had to simplify to illustrate the concept but now I think the idea is illustrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window function row_number() within a CASE is an option

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Flag = case when row_number() over (partition by Fruit order by [Order Time]) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
 From YourTable
 Order by [Order Time]
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: This was great and worked perfectly. What if I wanted to add a Flag2 column that counts how many time it has been seen so far? In that case the example would have Flag2 = 1/1/1/1/2/2/1

Comment: @ZakFischer  Add a column sum(1) over (partition by Fruit order by [Order Time])   or take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=eb22cb4e311cd7f7365b39c30d012bd8

Comment: @ZakFischer  Failed to mention, you can use sum(1) or even row_number()